passing constructor arguments to 0-arg constructor at contract create
Suppose the contract (written in Solidity) has only one constructor, and that a 0-arg constructor.  Suppose now in a contract create transaction you supply constructor arguments.
Is that an error that is detected, or not?
(I suspect not, but can't find documentation at Solidity nor in any posting/tutorial I've been able to locate. It would require the compiler to generate the code to check that, but does it?)

When you compile a Solidity contract, the constructor's bytecode is included in the creation bytecode of the contract. If the constructor takes no arguments, the bytecode is designed to operate without expecting any additional input data.
So, if additional input data is passed as constructor arguments, it will result in an error. The EVM will not be able to correctly parse and execute the constructor's bytecode, leading to a failed contract creation transaction.
This error is detected at runtime when the contract creation transaction is executed. The EVM checks the input data against the expected constructor parameters and, if there is a mismatch, the transaction will revert.

Can you be more specific about how the check for constructor parameters is done?  The EVM only executes opcodes. The EVM CREATE opcode is defined to execte "initialization code" that exists somewhere.  That's where the check must reside - not something done by the CREATE opcode.  So I'm really asking: Is that done by generated bytecode in the contract?  TY!

Yes, the check for constructor parameters is implicitly done by the generated initialization bytecode. The EVM executes this bytecode during contract creation, and if there is a mismatch between the expected and provided constructor arguments, the transaction will fail due to the initialization code not handling the unexpected input data properly.
